# How to upgrade from InfluxDB 1.8 to 2.0

Tags: influxdb

What are the exact steps for upgrading InfluxDB v1.8.2 to the latest stable version (2.0.3 at time of writing)? (Ubuntu Bionic)

Specifically I installed v1.8.2 according to the InfluxDB docs at the time, and have tried following the [official upgrade docs](https://docs.influxdata.com/influxdb/v2.0/upgrade/v1-to-v2/) but have failed in the following ways:

1. The above page starts with "Use the influxd upgrade command to upgrade InfluxDB 1.x to InfluxDB 2.0." The more detailed instructions under the heading **Perform the Upgrade** say to download the source, unpackage it to $PATH, stop influx which I do with `sudo service influxdb stop`, then run `influxd upgrade`, but when I do the latter I get `unknown command "upgrade"`. I can however run `influxd version` which shows version 1.8.2.
2. Instructions on the download page for Ubuntu/Debian state run the following commands: `wget https://dl.influxdata.com/influxdb/releases/influxdb2_2.0.3_amd64.deb` then `sudo dpkg -i influxdb2_2.0.3_amd64.deb`, however the latter returns the following error:

   ```
   dpkg: regarding influxdb2_2.0.3_amd64.deb containing influxdb2:
   influxdb2 conflicts with influxdb
   influxdb (version 1.8.2-1) is present and installed.

   dpkg: error processing archive influxdb2_2.0.3_amd64.deb (--install):
   conflicting packages - not installing influxdb2
   Errors were encountered while processing:
   influxdb2_2.0.3_amd64.deb
   ```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Hi there! We are working on the exact same thing and we got it up and running, but it feels really messy as we had to push binaries into place and such. I think the official documentation for the upgrade to 2.0 tries to be as platform agnostic as possible but that goes for a lack of comprehension. We will try and work out the "Linux Way". Did you have any successes yet?

Comment: Also, I think they created the .deb package in a way that it conflicts with the 1.x versions which seems intentional and is probably a good idea. I guess you would have to uninstall 1.x prior to installing the 2.x release. I will update as soon as we get new intel.

Answer (score -1):

You can't have both InfluDB v1.8 and v2.0 installed as DEB packages at the same time, because both want to bind to the same default port.

So first make a backup of your v1.8 data, then `apt-get remove` your v1.8 package. Then you can `dpkg -i` the v2.0 package.

Once you've done that, your `influxd version` should return 2.0.3, at which point `influxd upgrade` should work.